# How to pass a jpg id between activities Android

Tags: android, imageview, drawable

I have a gridView with imageViews in one Activity and I want to load one of them in other activity on a new ImageView when select it, but i have no results

Activity 1:

```
public class Level extends Activity{
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.level);

    GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridviewLevel);
    ImageAdapter ia = new ImageAdapter(this);
    gridview.setAdapter(ia);

    gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(Level.this, "" + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            initImageCheck( v.getId());
        }
    });
}

public void initImageCheck(int id){
    Intent intentIC = new Intent(this, ImageCheck.class);
    intentIC.putExtra("ID", id);
    startActivity(intentIC);
}
```

}

Activity 2:

```
public class ImageCheck extends Activity{
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.image_check);

    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    int id = extras.getInt("ID");

    ImageView imgView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageViewCheck);

    imgView.setImageResource(id);
}
```

}

Whats the problem??? Thanks.

Comment: In the `Toast` (`Toast.makeText(Level.this, "" + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();`), you are checking for the _position_ but  you are passing the **ID of the View** to your method. Why?

Comment: yes that was wrong. I've just fixed it. xD

Comment: No. i've used the idImage from the adapter but i get no results. In any case the Toast is not involved in what i want to do.

Answer (score 2):

`v.getId()` is the ID of the View, not of the image resource.

Have `ImageAdapter` also hold the id of resource used per item, and also provide a method like `getResourceIdForItem(int position)`.

Comment: Thanks but i have no resutls. That method doesn't appear. Any other suggestion?